# Integral of $\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^2x}$ from 0 to $\pi/2$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, infinity

I am trying yo find $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^2x}dx$.

So far I have tried using the substitution $\tan u=\sin x$ which led me to $$\int_{u=0}^{u=\pi/4}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}du$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\tan u}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2u}}du$$ which I initially thought would allow me to rearrange to

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cot^2u+1}}du$$ so that I could use the result

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}du=ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})$$ However I realised that this would not work because when I divided by tanu II divided by zero as one of my limits is u=0...

I would be very grateful for any hints and also if anyone has any tips for integrating tricky trig functions like this one. I really would like to develop y integrating toolbox so that I can tackle integrals like this in the future...

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If $\tan(u)=\sin(x)$, then $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\tan^2(u)}$, not $\sqrt{1+\tan^2(u)}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^2x}\,dx=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x}{2-\cos^2x}\,dx
$$
Do $t=\cos x$, so $dt=-\sin x\,dx$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int_{1}^{0}-\frac{1}{2-t^2}\,dt
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I keep getting the wrong answer and I was wondering if you could point out my mistake... From the above, you get $\int_0^1\frac{1}{2-t^2}dt$ and using the general result $\int\frac{1}{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}ln|\frac{a+x}{a-x}|$ , I get $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}ln|\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}-1}|$ which simplifies to $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}ln(3+2\sqrt{2})$, but the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}ln(1+\sqrt{2})$???

Comment: Never mind! I see that 3+2sqrt2= (1+sqrt2)^2, so it simplifies! Thank you again to both who answered!

Comment: @21joanna12 Yes: $\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}-1}=(\sqrt{2}+1)^2$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$

Set $\cos x=-u$

See [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ10/integ10.html)